# Сравнение gps координат с координатами из базы

Tags: алгоритм, javascript

Хочу реализовать следующее. 
Допустим пользователь перемещается на автомобиле. 
И при достижении определенного места, срабатывало событие.

Интересует вопрос, как описать радиус точки назначения ? т.к. в точные значения переместиться неудастся, да это и не нужно. 
Допустим если клиент подъехал к месту в радиусе 30 метров, то запустить событие?

Как описать функцию радиуса?

Comment: теорема Пифагора знакома? `r = sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если расстояние между текущим местонахождением и точкой меньше радиуса, то случается событие. Расстояние пересчитывается при каждом обновлении gps координат.

Насколько я знаю, есть формулы которые позволяются узнать расстояние между двумя географическими точками. Может быть погрешность, из-за округлости Земли, но в пределах десятков километров она, думаю, не значительная.

upd: Ещё нужно не забыть ситуацию, когда при скорость движения высока, а радиус мал. В таком случае есть вероятность проскочить точку.

Comment: А вот и сами формулы: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance